# Windows batch file: choosing a file from a directory based on directory name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I don't do windows batch programming, nor do I need to go that far down the rabbit hole.

I have directory structures as such:

```
dir1000000/file.txt
dir2000000_1/file.txt
dir2000000_2/file.txt
```

I need to select the `file.txt` from the path with the lexicographically greatest value, i.e. `dir2000000_2/file.txt`. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: By "the lexicographically greatest value", do you mean the last one in the display/sort order, or the longest one, or the last one in an ordered family/branch...?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

It's really a timestamp, so all the files have the same base string length, and then longer strings past the underscore should be alphabetically greater, as well as newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the file is always file.txt and only the directory is variable...

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('DIR /ad/b/on') DO SET mydir=%%a
SET myfile=%mydir%\file.txt
```

Comment: +1 As an FYI, since the OP's comment indicates he might just be sorting by date, he could swap out the `DIR /ad/b/on` for `DIR /ad/b/od` if that's the case.